Looker studio removes duplicates on table view
I created a dashboard on looker studio for a survey results .
on the table view  that contains only project name, rating and comments the looker is not counting the duplicate data which means comment is null has the same rating and same projects
I want it to show all data and not considering this data as duplicate
I tried adding name as a unique value and it works but indeed i don't want to add name on the table
